# Loading html data in WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I am working on an example app to be able to load simple html data into a webview without distorting the content. In my Activity, I am using the org.apache.http packages to connect to a website and retrieve it's content in a private method openGoogleHomePage().

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");

get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
get.setHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1-update1; de-de; HTC Desire 1.19.161.5 Build/ERE27) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

String data = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
data = data.replaceAll("%", "&#37;");
return data;
```

When I compare 'data' to the actual html content response upon opening http://www.google.com on firefox browser, the content is the same. However, when I try to load this 'data' into a webview, I don't see anything like it.

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
    setContentView(layout);
WebView browser = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webPage);

browserSettings = browser.getSettings();
browserSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
browserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browserSettings.setSavePassword(false);
browserSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
browserSettings.setSupportZoom(false);

browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});

String htmlData = openGoogleHomePage();
if (htmlData != null) {
    browser.loadData(htmlData, "text/html", HTTP.UTF_8);
}
```

Whatelse do I have to change in my code to be able to view in the webview exactly as I do in the browser on a PC? On the other hand, without going through the painstaking process of invoking the URL using the http packages, and instead invoking the url from the webview using webview.loadUrl("http://www.gooogle.com") of course, retrieves the mobile version of the search-giant's page, which is way different than the PC browser version.

In short, I want to see in my webview exactly what I see on a PC browser, after handling the http invocations in my native custom code.

Also, if someone could show some pointers at handling url redirects, that would be of much help.

Comment: you can save into a file and make the webview point to it :D

Answer (score 1):

Some mobile device detection could be based on the user-agent. 
Try setting the UserAgent in the WebView to use Desktop counterpart by adding one more setting to your WebView.

```
  browserSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0");
```