# Setting WebView to view Desktop Site and Not Mobile Site

Tags: android, android-webview

I've done quite a lot of research on Stack Overflow and a lot of Google research but nothing I find is actually working out for me. I want the site to view the desktop site instead of the mobile site. How do I do this? I want it to directly go to the Desktop site.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.apotter96.webs.com/");
}
```

Comment: Don't think its really a possibility, since its out of your hands what their site does when it notices you're a mobile. Maybe if you find out how they recognize and save it, you can manipulate it with some javascript or whatever

Comment: How am I supposed to use javascript to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for some method to change the user's Agent String? Have you searched around for that it seems there are quite a few resources when I google it.

Comment: You can use `setDesktopMode(true)` from [this library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) or read how it's [implemented](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/6db5a76b781c636513282b9efed993e705db4570/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L358).

Comment: setting myWebView.setInitialScale(100); worked for me, but before myWebView.loadUrl() add webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73670361/19900349

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Change the user agent of webview

```
 String newUA="Foo/"; // Change this to desired UA
```

like

```
 String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Comment: How do I enable Flash Player?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview/6855609#6855609

Comment: This is working fine, but I got a sideeffect because of using this setting. The webview is not destroyed in onDestroy() of the activity. I am using mWebView.destroy(); in the onDestroy funtion of the activity

Comment: @BhanuSharma I have posted my answer can check that and let me know

Comment: watch for user agent string , it is now slightly modified and also include chrome version.
that might effect the end result ...  look at developer's official : https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating#UserAgent

Answer (score 22):

This method helps you to set DesktopMode on webview

```
public void setDesktopMode(WebView webView,boolean enabled) {
    String newUserAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
    if (enabled) {
        try {
            String ua = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
            String androidOSString = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().substring(ua.indexOf("("), ua.indexOf(")") + 1);
            newUserAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().replace(androidOSString, "(X11; Linux x86_64)");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        newUserAgent = null;
    }

    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUserAgent);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(enabled);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(enabled);
    webView.reload();
}
```

Call it like that

Mobile mode : `setDesktopMode(webView, false);`

Desktop mode : `setDesktopMode(webView, true);`

**For Kotlin:**

```
fun setDesktopMode(webView: WebView, enabled: Boolean) {
    var newUserAgent: String? = webView.settings.userAgentString
    if (enabled) {
        try {
            val ua: String = webView.settings.userAgentString
            val androidOSString: String = webView.settings.userAgentString.substring(
                ua.indexOf("("),
                ua.indexOf(")") + 1
            )
            newUserAgent = webView.settings.userAgentString.replace(androidOSString, "(X11; Linux x86_64)")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {
        newUserAgent = null
    }
    webView.settings.apply {
        userAgentString = newUserAgent
        useWideViewPort = enabled
        loadWithOverviewMode = enabled
    }
    webView.reload()
}
```

Comment: I am trying to open web.whatsapp.com ,,the site keeps on loading

Answer (score 18):

You can use WebView to show view as Desktop Site with fit in mobile display.

```
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: this setting Worked Like charm.

Answer (score 6):

Some sites don't use User Agent to determine if then have to show the mobile or the desktop version of the Page.
Some pages uses screen size to do this.

I build an app to use a page in desktop mode, but it doesn't work properly. Always show the mobile version because the page uses screen size and not User Agent String.

Answer (score 6):

The only solution which worked for me (javascript will be executed many times, but this is the only working solution for now)

```
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
           view.evaluateJavascript("document.querySelector('meta[name=\"viewport\"]').setAttribute('content', 'width=1024px, initial-scale=' + (document.documentElement.clientWidth / 1024));", null);
        }
```

You can set desktop UA string too

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: Everything else in here is simply about the user agent which is not enough for many web sites. That one works for me too, thanks for sharing. That should be the accepted answer until something better comes along.

Comment: I tried a few things to find away to have the initial scale zoomed out to fit the screen but none I was happy with. Looks like I'm going to leave it to 1.0 and let user zoom out for now.

Comment: Found it: view.evaluateJavascript("document.querySelector('meta[name=\"viewport\"]').setAttribute('content', 'width=1024px, initial-scale=' + (window.screen.width / 1024));", null)

Comment: You also need to make sure wide viewport is enabled: webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

Comment: @Slion saved my night !! :P

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure you can do JavaScript injection from `onPageStarted` as it seems it is called after the main HTML document has been loaded. Thus it won't be called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

A little update to accepted answer.This is the new string. Wrote this because someone had an issue of "Update Browser" in the comments.

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1";
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have update browser error you can try this to set apple safari UA or replace UA with `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0`
This worked 100% for me.

```
webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(12);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50";
        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        webview.loadUrl("https://solveforum.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is in **Java**:

**- Mobile / Phone Mode**

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(110);
```

- **Desktop Mode**

  ```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the replies above, changing User-Agent, `setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)` and `setUseWideViewPort(true)` is NOT enough to force the "desktop" mode.

The best resource I found is [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/web-page-layout.md#the-decision-diagram) doc from the WebView team. The diagram is really helpful to understand how it actually works.

It all comes down to handling the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag). Unfortunately, WebView API alone does not allow you to fully match Chrome at the moment. The only way I found was using JS hacks.

Assuming that you want to match Chrome behaviour in WebView on Android, here's what worked for me (or see the [code here](https://github.com/duckduckgo/content-scope-scripts/blob/88feb44ea7d090981730b0105720c9f905804ddc/src/features/web-compat.js#L514)):

1. `setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING)`, `setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)`, and `setUseWideViewPort(true)` **at all times, even when not in "desktop" mode**
2. In **non-desktop mode**, handle the WebView's weird special case: when there's a viewport meta tag **without `width`** and with **`initial-scale` != 1** (even if it's 1.00001), force `width=device-width` in the meta tag using JS. It's still a mystery for me, why this edge case exists.
3. Set User-Agent (both in JS API and HTTP header) depending on the desktop/mobile mode
4. In **desktop mode**, OR in mobile mode when there's **no viewport tag** on the page, force the viewport meta tag content to `width=980` using JS. 980 is [hardcoded](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/css/resolver/viewport_style_resolver.cc;l=71-90?q=980%20filepath:viewport) in Chromium source. On wider screens it's 1280, but that doesn't change the look too much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the user agent : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)

Here is an example :
[Loading html data in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397838/loading-html-data-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

After long search this worked for me -

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");

    String userAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();

    try {
        String androidString = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().
                substring(userAgent.indexOf("("),userAgent.indexOf(")")+ 1);

        userAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().replace(androidString,"X11; Linux x86_64");

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
    webView.reload();
```