# Can we handle Event of Default web browser?

Tags: android

Very much new issue for me. My requirement is to handle event of default web browser. Is it possible to handle it's events programetically? Like if we open any website on web browser which is installed in our application, and if we are viewing mobile version of that website than we can switch to the desktop version of that website also. I want to do handle same event on my application.

In my application there is one ON/OFF Toogle Button, when user click on ON, than only desktop version of any website should be opened whenever user tries to open any website on browser[I.E not webview]

The only thing i could find on web is this url for this issue

[Setting WebView to view Desktop Site and Not Mobile Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site)

I refer developer guideline http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html but could not find any thinng on it.

I am not sure is it possible or not

If any one have any suggestion or idea than it will be appreciated

Thanks