# Show whatsapp barcode webpage in webview

Tags: android, webview, whatsapp

I am trying to show this link in android app in webview but the web loads in android device is different from showing in Google Chrome.

Whatsapp link is here :https://web.whatsapp.com/

I am using this code in android to load the above page but it does not load the same page.

```
mWebView .loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");// https://tekdude.blogspot.in/");
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
setContentView(mWebView );
```

Comment: Why would they allow mobile viewing of a desktop link webpage?

Comment: @Stefan so, is there any method to show the above webpage same in android device like in google chrome?

Comment: Probably not. What are you trying to achieve? Linking whatsapp to your webview in your own app?

Comment: @Stefan yes i want to show the QRCode from that web page inside my webview in android app

Answer (score 4):

You can Use This Code, It Worked For me!!

Copy this code to inside `OnCreate` Method!! You can edit code according to your requirement.

```
webView.loadUrl(YOUR URL HERE);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Win64; x64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0");
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setNeedInitialFocus(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
//webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(true);
webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.setInitialScale(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the user agent of webview
like

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Alternatively you can also change the settings without changing user agent

```
 webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
 webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
 webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
 webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
 webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I added this line, but it says i should update firfox ?

Comment: Change the version..put the lastest one and correct my ans too :p

Comment: @Pir Fahim Shah check the edit please. alternate way

Comment: @Pir Fahim Shah did it help?

Comment: @no it does not work, it is not displaying the same QRcode page of the whats app

Comment: Huh ! Desktop view is the only way to show this code in phones

Comment: @really the above link is showing different screen in phone with this code from the desktop google chrome screen

Comment: @PirFahimShah by default it will detect android as your default browser..google more on desktop view solution ..gud luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try with changing user agent of your web view.

Example:

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Check this link
[Setting WebView to view Desktop Site and Not Mobile Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site)