# Force webview to open whatsapp web in dekstop mode

Tags: java, android, webview, user-agent, whatsapp

I'm trying to create an webview android app that opens whatsapp web, but whatsapp web shows another browser recommendations or update your browser. I tried many different user-agents with no luck. I'm new to this and this is my first app. I thought I'll start easy :')

```
    package app.whatstab;
```

`import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//        String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4)     Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
        String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/4.0";
        webSettings.setUserAgentString(newUA);

        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)     {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
        {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    { //if back key is pressed
        if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&& mWebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;

        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
    }
}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site#14688100

Comment: It looks the same but it didn't help. I think that whatsapp is the difference. Maybe they check other strings than only user agent