# App Inventor 2 - webview request desktop site

Tags: app-inventor

I want to display this site https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/yahoo?Ltr=1  in desktop mode using WebViewer. How do I do this in app inventor? Yahoo detects my android phone and it returns mobile mode instead of desktop mode.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer**
Now with the extension feature we are able to modify the user agent of the webviewer... you can try one of the following extensions:

[Custom Webview by vknow360](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/customwebview-an-extended-form-of-web-viewer/9934?u=taifun)
or
[Webview Tools Extension Version 8 by LukeGackle](http://thunkableblocks.blogspot.com/2017/06/webviewtools-extension-for-app-inventor.html)

**Previous answer**
Unfortunately that's not possible in App Inventor.

You can't change the user agent of the webview as you can do it for the Android webviewer, see for example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14688100/1545993

Sorry, not possible.