# Load an url in desktop view format in android studio

Tags: android

I want to create an android app that will load an url in webview and it must be desktop view format. I have tried it but not working.`String userAgentCustom= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0"; webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgentCustom);`

Comment: use this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600501/5773037

Comment: I have already tried it but not working.

Comment: show your code snippet