# Setting WebView to view Desktop Site rather than Mobile Site

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have taken **reference** to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site)** **previously asked** question. I have tried doing this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview=findViewById(R.id.webview1);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("https://facebook.com");
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (webview.canGoBack()) {
                    webview.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

and did what an answer suggested, but as in the comments of one of the answer to the reference question, it asks me to **update my browser**. My aim is to open the "Whatsapp-Web" desktop site inside my webview. What should I do regarding the browser and any advice regarding opening whatsapp.
Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** This is the new Code that I am trying with a new User Agent

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1";
    whatsapp.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

    String DESKTOP_USERAGENT = whatsapp.getSettings().getUserAgentString ();
    DESKTOP_USERAGENT = DESKTOP_USERAGENT.replace("Mobile ","");
    whatsapp.getSettings().setUserAgentString(DESKTOP_USERAGENT);

    whatsapp.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    whatsapp.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    whatsapp.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

Comment: Firefox 4 sounds like an old browser. Get a different user agent. You can get one by opening your regular browser on pc then visit https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent

Comment: Also, the StackOverflow link you looked at is **5 years old**. Check the date whenever you use a link as reference

Comment: I tried many other links on the site but this was the one that was the closest to a working state, hence i used this question.

Comment: I tried many different kinds of user strings but none worked. they just opened the mobile site. I was looking for a different approach maybe, if that worked.

Comment: Have you already tried what I suggested? Use a modern desktop user agent?

Comment: yes, but it opened mobile sites only.. could you give me a newer user agent if you have one that might open desktop site?? Maybe the ones I tried were not correct or something..

Comment: Can you show me what user agent you are using?

Comment: isnt it the one in the code?? Im new to this..

Comment: I told you to click the link I provided. It's not difficult, all you have to do is click on it, then the site will display a newer user-agent for you.

Comment: ohh inside that.. in that I used "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"... and it worked but only for mobile sites.. but it did not direct to desktop sites... is there a problem you see that I might have missed??

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView to show view as Desktop Site with fit in mobile display.

```
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Let me know if this solution works