# How to open a site in Desktop mode in flutter web_view?

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to open web.whatsapp.com web in mobile WebView.
Web view is working fine in flutter app but, I want the site to be opened in desktop preference.

**This is what I am getting**

[image]

**Expected**

[image]
**so that I can scan the QR code**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720983/how-to-add-desktop-version-of-website-in-flutter-app

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open website inside desktop app, use this dependency
https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_webview_window

Comment: It just opens zoomed out view, not the desktop version of site

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200153/whatsapp-web-desktop-mode-in-flutter).

Used [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package in my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WhatsappWeb extends StatefulWidget {
  const WhatsappWeb({super.key});

  @override
  State<WhatsappWeb> createState() => WebViewState();
}

WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController();

class WebViewState extends State<WhatsappWeb> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    webViewController = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.white)
      ..setUserAgent(
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15')
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https:web.whatsapp.com'));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    webViewController.loadRequest(Uri.parse('about:blank'));
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => PopScope(
        onPopInvoked: (_) => onWillPop,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
            ),
          ),
          body: WebViewWidget(controller: webViewController),
        ),
      );
}

Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
  if (await webViewController.canGoBack()) {
    webViewController.goBack();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]