# Whatsapp web Desktop mode in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform, whatsapp, webview-flutter

I want to open Whatsapp Web Desktop mode in my flutter app
As shown in picture
[Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwJcy.jpg)

I am used [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) [webview_flutter_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus) packages but both results same.

my initial url is

> https://web.whatsapp.com

The code i am using are as follow

```html
class WhatsAppWebScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  WhatsAppWebScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // late Completer<WebViewController> controller;

  @override
  State<WhatsAppWebScreen> createState() => _WhatsAppWebScreenState();
}

class _WhatsAppWebScreenState extends State<WhatsAppWebScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const DrawerWidget(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("WhatsAppWeb"),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF128D7E),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: 80.h,
          child: WebViewPlus(
            initialUrl: 'https://web.whatsapp.com',
          
            userAgent:
               "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Every Time i run this code the url redirects into

> [www.whatsapp.com](http://www.whatsapp.com)

and results like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcqZ4.jpg)

I try many different user agents strings but the same result.

I used navigationdelegate parameter to prevent redirection of url. but then it shows blank screen

```
navigationDelegate: (request) {
       if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.whatsapp.com/')) {
         print('blocking navigation to $request}');
       
         return NavigationDecision.prevent;
       }
      print('allowing navigation to $request');
       return NavigationDecision.navigate;
    },
    onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
       _controller.complete(webViewController);
     },
```

How can i open whatsapp web desktop mode in my flutter app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://web.whatsapp.com',
      
        userAgent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15",
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
```