# How to change from mobile view to desktop view in a webview

Tags: android

I created a `webview` into my app, and I want to put a `button` so the user can switch from mobile view to the desktop view and back every time he want.

I have already seen other questions about this argument but none solves my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that explains what you tried and what problems you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to change the user agent of the WebView.
You could try with this:

```
 String newUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

(Based on [Setting WebView to view Desktop Site and Not Mobile Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site))

I will leave you a list of other user agents you can use here:
https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/