# Android Web View looks weird on Tablet but fine on emulator in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, tablet

I made a WebView and the site looks completely fine on the Emulator but when I install the APK on my Samsung Galaxy Tab A it looks really messed up.

This is what it's supposed to look like:
[image]

and this is what it looks like on my tablet:

[image]
[image]

I have 3 xml files:

activity_webappview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.cwm.cwmapp.webappview">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text=""
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".webappview"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried to mess around with them a bit but it only ever changed the results in the emulator and would always stay the same on the tablet.

Does anybody know why it looks so messed up on the tablet?

Comment: A `WebView` is not designed to have children, so I would expect strange results from having a `WebView` attempt to hold a `Button`.

Comment: Never had any problems with that button before @CommonsWare, I just removed it to test if it would change anything. Problem sustains.

Comment: But just don't do it because it can cause other problems. Why should you do it if it is not designed to be used that way?

Comment: I already said I removed it, no point in commenting the same thing twice, especially because it’s in no way related to my question.

Comment: Could that be a bootstrap issue or something? As the components did get full width it looks like the website is guessing you are using a handheld and is showing a optimized layout for your device. This could be caused by low resolution of your display or the browser is using a different agent.  For further information how to handle this look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site

Comment: Thanks Hatzen this was actually the only useful tip and led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.
Since this was loaded from files and not an actual website, I couldn't access the referenced stylesheet which was a link to an online stylesheet.

Turns out the button could stay after all... :^)