# ESP32 httpd: Header fields are too long for the server to interpret

Tags: android-webview, esp32, arduino-esp32

I want to stream to WebView inside a Anrdoid App.

My code is:

```
WebView cam = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Cam);
        cam.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        cam.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        cam.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        cam.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        cam.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        cam.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.10");
```

It works in emulator but if I install the App at smartphone it doesnt  work. I get an error

```
Header fields are too long for the server to interpret
```

How do get rid of this error?

Answer (score 7):

Edit `sdkconfig` and increase `CONFIG_HTTPD_MAX_REQ_HDR_LEN` e.g. like this:

```
CONFIG_HTTPD_MAX_REQ_HDR_LEN=1024
```

The default is 512. Don't set it too high to avoid wasting RAM, remember that ESP32 doesn't have much RAM.

Also it's best to set the User-Agent header in your WebView, otherwise a system-default User-Agent will be used, which can be longer or shorter depending on the actual Android device.

```
    cam.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (my app)");
```

The above might just fit within the default 512 bytes for the request length.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with Unity. In my app, I was struggling with

```
Header fields are too long for the server to interpret
```

but Chrome browser in android was showing it right. I changed ESP32 code but not worked.
When I try opening it in desktop mode it worked.
You had to change your "User Agent" setting.

```
 String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

like in:
[Setting WebView to view Desktop Site and Not Mobile Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site)