# How can I show Desktop Mode only in Web view of mobile app in android studio?

Tags: android

My Java code for Webview in Fragment is as under:

```
public class kvkfragment extends Fragment {

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public kvkfragment() {        
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kvkfragment, container, false);

        progressBar = myView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        WebView mywebView = myView.findViewById(R.id.mywebView);
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in");
        mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        mywebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mywebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        mywebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (XHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        mywebView.setInitialScale(1);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
}
```

I want to get it show as Desktop Mode of this webview in fragment of my android app. Therefore, please suggest me the new code for setting the "Desktop Mode" in Webview of fragment activity in Android Studio.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510872/12153321

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting WebView to view Desktop Site and Not Mobile Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site)